# How to add where condition into relatation model?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hy

I have a problem, with my query, I would like to add where contidion, but I don't know where and how.

This is the first relation model:

```
class FreightTaskBrowserModel(
    @Embedded val freightTask: FreightTask,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "oid",
        entityColumn = "freight_task_id",
        entity = FreightTaskRow::class
    )
    val freightTaskRowWithStatus: List<FreightTaskRowWithStatus>
) {}
```

And inside this, there is another:

```
class FreightTaskRowWithStatus(
    @Embedded var freightTaskRow: FreightTaskRowWithUnitName,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "oid",
        entityColumn = "oid"
    )
    var rowStatusModel: RowStatusModel? = null
)
{}
```

There is a status property inside `rowStatusModel`, and also a status property inside `freightTaskRow`, and I would like to filter all row where `status = null` or 0

And finally it is my repository funcion:

```
fun getAllFiltered(searchText: String, dateFrom: Date, dateTo: Date, searchInCode: Int): LiveData<PagedList<FreightTaskBrowserModel>> {
        val bindLists = ArrayList<Any>()
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        val dateFromLong = dateFrom.time
        val dateToLong = dateTo.time

        sb.append("SELECT * FROM freight_task where ")

        when(searchInCode){
            FreightTaskSearchTypes.SEARCH_IN_ADDRESS.code -> {
                sb.append(" (load_customer_address like ? or unload_customer_address like ?) ")
                bindLists.add(searchText)
                bindLists.add(searchText)
            }
            FreightTaskSearchTypes.DOCUMENT_NUMBER.code  -> {
                sb.append(" document_number like ? ")
                bindLists.add(searchText)
            }
            else -> {
                sb.append(" client_name like ? ")
                bindLists.add(searchText)
            }
        }

        sb.append(" and delivery_deadline >= ? AND delivery_deadline <= ?")
        bindLists.add(dateFromLong)
        bindLists.add(dateToLong)

        val simpleSQLiteQuery = SimpleSQLiteQuery(sb.toString(), bindLists.toTypedArray())

        val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
            .setPageSize(50)
            .setPrefetchDistance(50)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(100).build()

        return LivePagedListBuilder(
            dao.getFreightTaskWithRowsFiltered(simpleSQLiteQuery),
            config
        ).build()
```

FreightTask Table:

```
@Entity(tableName = FreightTask.TABLE_NAME)
class FreightTask(
    @Json(name = "Oid")
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "oid")
    var oid: String = "",

    @Json(name = "LoadCustomersAddress")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "load_customer_address")
    var loadCustomerAddress: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "UnloadCustomersAddress")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "unload_customer_address")
    var unloadCustomerAddress: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "DeliveryId")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "delivery_id")
    var deliveryId: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "DeliveryDeadline")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "delivery_deadline")
    var deliveryDeadline: Date? = null,

    @Json(name = "ClientPhoneNumber")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "client_phone_number")
    var clientPhoneNumber: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "SupplierPhoneNumber")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "supplier_phone_number")
    var supplierPhoneNumber: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "UnloadAddressCoordinate")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "unload_address_coordinate")
    var unloadAddressCoordinate: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "LoadAddressCoordinate")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "load_address_coordinate")
    var loadAddressCoordinate: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "Comment")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "comment")
    var comment: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "ClientName")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "client_name")
    var clientName: String = "",

    @Json(name = "DocumentNumber")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "document_number")
    var documentNumber: String = "",

    @Json(name = "HeadStatus")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "head_status")
    var headStatus: Int? = null,

    @Ignore
    @Json(name = "Rows")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "freight_task_rows") var freightTaskRows: List<FreightTaskRow>? = null
)
{
    companion object {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "freight_task"
    }
}
```

FreightTaskRow Table:

```
@Entity(tableName = FreightTaskRow.TABLE_NAME)
data class FreightTaskRow(
    @Json(name = "Oid")
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "oid")
    var oid: String = "",

    @ColumnInfo(name = "freight_task_id")
    var freightTaskId: String = "",

    @Json(name = "ProductName")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_name")
    var productName: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "Qtt")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "qtt")
    var qtt: BigDecimal? = null,

    @Json(name = "EkaerNumber")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ekaer_number")
    var ekaerNumber: String? = null,

    @Json(name = "UnitId")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "unit_id")
    var unitId: String = "",

    @Json(name = "RowStatus")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "row_status")
    var rowStatus: Int? = null,

    @Json(name = "AcceptedWeightDifference")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "accepted_weight_difference")
    var acceptedWeightDifference: BigDecimal? = null
) {
    companion object {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "freight_task_rows"
    }
}
```

RowStatusModel Table

```
@Entity(tableName = RowStatusModel.TABLE_NAME)
data class RowStatusModel(
    @Json(name = "Oid")
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "oid")
    var oid: String = "",

    @Json(name = "Qtt")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "qtt")
    var qtt: BigDecimal? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
    var status: Int? = null,

    @Json(name = "Status")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "row_status")
    var rowStatus: Int? = null,
) {
    companion object{
        const val TABLE_NAME = "row_status_models"
    }
}
```

Updated:
RowStatusModel Oid is equal to FreightTaskRow oid

What is the simplest solution of this problem?

Comment: You can write queries based on filter, right? Something like this: `@Query(select * from freight_task where client_name = : client_name)
suspend fun getFreightTasksWithClientName(client_name: String)`

Comment: Thanks, but the filtering in freight_tasks is works perfectily. I would like to filter in the joined table, FreightTaskRowWithStatus class where there is a status prop inside rowStatusModel, and inside freightTaskRow

Comment: If possible share the all the data models to follow the complete design.

Comment: Off course, I added the required models

Comment: Did you read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-relationships) ?

Comment: Yes I read it, but it don't contains any relevant information for my problem